# Create points on faces around the location of another object

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using 3.1.

I can't find how to use the geometry nodes to distribute points around the location of another object in spite this is demonstrated in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8LeR_yfRZ0) (at 45:40) made with version 3.0.

The tutorial where the points follow the cube when the cube is moved:

[image]

It's based on using the `Selection` input of the `Distribute Points on Faces` nodes. My own setting:

[image]

- The size of the area where points are created is not manageable, Points are created anywhere on the plane. Selection value it not processed the same way, it seems the node just checks the value is positive to create nodes at any location, else no nodes are created.
- As points are distributed irrespective of the distance from the empty, moving the empty doesn't move the points.

Can someone explain what changed since the tutorial was recorded, and what is the new solution to create point around another object location?

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute points on the mesh then use a translate instances node and multiply a noise by the normal of the object you distributed it on. This will randomly offset the points or instances around the object.